# Firefox extension to obtain IP address through the current tab

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a Firefox web extension that obtains the IP address of the host through the current tab. In details, I have a Firefox extension that is able to assign a specific proxy to a specific container and so to a specific tab! So what I need is to be able to get the Internet IP address resolved via the specific tab (so the specific proxy assigned to the container of that tab).

My guess is to use [tabs.executeScript()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript), but I'm not sure.

What do you think? Could you please provide a possible code solution to fetch the IP address through the currently active tab?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The process will have these steps:

#### 1. Get the details of the active tab

It depends on where and how the process initiated.

- Some APIs provide the details of the tab i.e [tabs.Tab](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab), for example [menus.onClicked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/menus/onClicked)
- Otherwise you have to get it, e.g.

```js
const tab = await browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true});
const activeTab = tab[0];
```

#### 2. Get the IP

- Check if the hostname is domain or IP
- If it is IP, then use it
- If it is domain, then get the IP for that hostname e.g. with [dns.resolve()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/dns/resolve)

```js
const result = await browser.dns.resolve('example.com');
```

Comment: I tried `browser.dns.resolve...` and I get `TypeError: chrome.dns is undefined`

Comment: @Briston12 To use this API, an extension must request the "dns" permission in its `manifest.json` file. Have you given it the permission?

Comment: ok ti worked using the "dns" permission. The problem is that this way I get the IP of the hostname, but I need the IP of the host passing through the tab to resolve it, because each tab connectes to the Internet via a specific proxy installed on the host and I need to get that public IP

Comment: @Briston12 You can get proxy details in [webRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest).